# '@lvalue $T7' is not identical to 'CGPoint!'

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm attempting to move a collection of nodes in SceneKit on iOS but I'm getting a cryptic error. Here's my code so far:

```
func renderer(aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
    let cubes = scene.rootNode.childNodesPassingTest { (node, stop) -> Bool in node.name == "cube" }
    for cube in cubes {
        cube.position = SCNVector3(x: cube.position.x - 5.0, y: cube.position.y, z: cube.position.z)
    }
}
```

On the line `cube.position = ...` I get `'@lvalue $T7' is not identical to 'CGPoint!'`

What does this error mean? Also, if there is a better way to loop over these nodes please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try explicitly casting 5.0 to `CGFloat`? So the `x` value would be `cube.position.x - CGFloat(5.0)`

Comment: @nickgraef same error.

Comment: did you ever figure out a fast way to loop over the nodes using a wildcard or  regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`childNodesPassingTest` returns an `[AnyObject]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNNode/childNodesPassingTest:) and Swift is having trouble figuring out what type `cube` is (apparently it thinks it's something who's `position` property is a `CGPoint!`).  Explicitly casting `cubes` to `[SCNNode]` should fix it:

```
for cube in cubes as [SCNNode] {
    cube.position = SCNVector3(x: cube.position.x - 5.0, y: cube.position.y, z: cube.position.z)
}
```